# How to block of loading resources from domain2.com on my website with Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: javascript, php, header, http-headers, content-security-policy

is it possible to blacklist a Content-Security-Policy or it has only whitelist function?

i want to block domain2.com/1.js from loading on my website.

i know Content-Security-Policy and method to change text/javascript to text/blocked
but i need to block only 1 domain and allow all others...

Comment: Don't think it's possible, but it'll probably be easier to just get the host ip address of that domain and create a `.htaccess` file in your web root. Put `Deny from 0.0.0.0` (replace 0.0.0.0 with the host ip) in it and your webserver will simply block that server from accessing anything on your website.

Comment: i want to block from loading domain2.com/1.js from my website in clients browsers... (